# Update Date field in SQLite

Tags: sqlite, c#-4.0

I am trying to update date column in SQLite (though .NET) and it seems not working.

Table as below:

```
 CREATE TABLE [Data] (
    [ID] INTEGER  PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(100)  NOT NULL,
    [DOB] DATE  NULL,
    [Occupation] NVARCHAR(100)  NULL,
    [Status] NVARCHAR(100)  NULL
    )
```

Insert statements as below:

```
Insert into Data(Name,DOB,Occupation,Status) values ('Harry Potter','2000-03-11','Carpenter','Single');
Insert into Data(Name,DOB,Occupation,Status) values ('Emily','1995-12-31','Doctor','Married');
Insert into Data(Name,DOB,Occupation,Status) values ('Jessica','1969-03-12','Nurse','Single');
Insert into Data(Name,DOB,Occupation,Status) values ('Tom Cruise','1975-03-13','Nanny','Single');
```

Data goes correctly in table. I can select and see.

But Update statement not working on Date column

```
update Data set  Name = 'Eric', DOB = '1969-3-12', Occupation = 'Nurse', Status = 'Single' where  ID=3;
```

What is wrong here?

Comment: Works for me. What do you mean with "not working"?

Comment: Mean not updating date field. Although updating others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was related to 32 and 64bit DLL's:

I found there are two solutions:

1. Either install SQLLite through Nuget as it gets the interop DLLS
2. or On server instead of 32bit DLL copy 64bit DLL.

It worked with above two options (Either)